# Sonarqube S2386, Mutable fields should not be "public static" false positive/negative

Tags: java, sonarqube

It seems that SonarLint considers `Collections.singletonList` as mutable even if the value in the list is immutable. Is this an error or are the rules not smart enough to check the mutability of the list type?

```
public static final List<String> STRING_LIST = Collections.singletonList("myString");
```

Conversely using `Collections.immutableList` seems to silence this error even if the value(s) in the list are mutable.

```
public static final List<Point> POINTS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.singletonList(new Point(1, 2)));
```

Above running SonarQube 6.2.

Comment: Seems `Collections.emptyList()` is also regarded as being mutable.